# Date math works on Chrome but not on Firefox or Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have this JavaScript in my page.

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) Date.parse(new Date()); 
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}
```

Endtime is a date like "2016-01-12 23:15:00"

My code works perfectly on Chrome but returns `NaN` in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code? On Chrome, and elsewhere, `var t = Date.parse(endtime) Date.parse(new Date());` should fail as a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this line:

```
var t = Date.parse(endtime) Date.parse(new Date());
```

is supposed to be

```
var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
```

The issue is the format of your endtime. Since you're not using a standard format, it may work in Chrome but not in other brosers. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> Because of the variances in parsing of date strings, it is recommended to always manually parse strings as results are inconsistent, especially across different ECMAScript implementations where strings like "2015-10-12 12:00:00" may be parsed to as NaN, UTC or local timezone.

Comment: The format of the Date causing the error.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some guesses around typos and incomplete information, but to get a *useful* time difference:

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - (new Date()).getTime();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

console.log(getTimeRemaining("2020-04-04"));
```

You don't need to `parse()` a `new Date()` -- it's not a string, and the results will be unpredictable. Simply use `getTime()` on the `Date` to get its millisecond representation.